# how to put imageviews half over parentlayout and half over childlayout

Tags: android, imageview

**how to put imageviewhalf over parentlayout and half over childlayout**

**xml code is below**

> i have tried with relativelayout and framelayout
>   **see pic in the link [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEVoG.jpg)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/school" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/school" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> i have addede link to clarify requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check this code 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/kidwithphone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_blue_one"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dude this layout will not remain same for all the device .because of margins

Comment: yes we have to keep a dimen values for all type of screens and we can edit that without specifying values

Comment: thanks for the answer but i achieved it by this ..[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795475/place-buttons-half-in-one-layout-parent-and-half-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically, in such a way that it works for any screen size, image and/or layout dimensions.

First, after creating the appropriate @dimen value, change this:

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/top_layout_height"
```

also, add an id to your frameLayout:

```
android:id="@+id/my_frame"
```

Finally, put this in your onCreate method:

```
//Get the image and topLayout height, as we'll need them later 
        int imageHeight = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),
                                                R.drawable.school,
                                                null).getMinimumHeight();
        int topLayoutHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.top_layout_height);

        //Get a reference to the FrameLayout then get its LayoutParameters
        FrameLayout myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_frame);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();

        //Set the top margin so that the FrameLayout is always in the middle
        params.setMargins(0, topLayoutHeight - imageHeight/2, 0, 0);

        //Apply the new parameters
        myFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here's the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiZPN.png)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i achieved it by this ..[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795475/place-buttons-half-in-one-layout-parent-and-half-in-another)